# Image not found using LiipImagineBundle and Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, liipimaginebundle

I want use LiipImagineBundle in Symfony3.

After installation I've configured the bundle in `config.yml`:

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
       default:
          web_path: ~ 
    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        my_thumb:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound
```

use in html code:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/t/1.jpg') | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
```

In rendered html:

```
<img src="http://localhost/test/web/app_dev.php/media/cache/resolve/my_thumb/test/web/t/1.jpg">
```

Image not found.

Comment: Does your image really exist?

Comment: Yes, image is exist

Comment: Image in /web/t/1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncommented this lines in php.ini into php folder.

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your image at path `web/t/1.jpg`. Also please check that image thumb is generated or not at path `http://localhost/test/web/app_dev.php/media/cache/resolve/my_thumb/test/web/t/1.jpg`.